# Desmarcar checkbox ao desmarcar outro checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Tenho dois `checkbox` em meu código. Gostaria que quando o **checkbox01** estivesse desmarcado, o **checkbox02** ficasse desabilitado e desmarcado. Porém, até agora só consegui desabilitá-lo, ou seja, apesar de desabilitado ele continua marcado.
OBS: o **checkbox01** sempre iniciará marcado ao carregar a página.

```js
function desabilitarEdesmarcar() {
  if (document.getElementById('checkbox01').checked) {
    document.getElementById('checkbox02').removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('checkbox02').removeAttribute("checked");
    document.getElementById('checkbox02').setAttribute("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="checkbox01" id="checkbox01" type="checkbox" onchange="desabilitarEdesmarcar()" checked=""> Checkbox01
<br>
<input id="checkbox02" id="checkbox02" type="checkbox"> Checkbox02
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apenas substitua a primeira linha do else:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox02').removeAttribute("checked");
```

por

```
document.getElementById('checkbox02').checked = false;
```

Comment: Uma alteração tão simples haha. Obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

> ..Gostaria que quando o checkbox01 estivesse desmarcado, o checkbox02 ficasse desabilitado e desmarcado...

Não precisa fazer [declarações condicionais](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) para isso, é uma questão simples de lógica:

- Independente de como que esteja checado o `checkbox01` toda vez que o clicar, o `checkbox02` deverá ter o seu estado como desmarcado.
- O `checkbox02` sempre estará habilitado contrariamente a checagem de `checkbox01`.

Fiz algumas mudanças no seu código:

- Organizei o HTML em dois [containers](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)
- Em cada containers coloquei um `checkbox` e um [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) associado ao `checkbox`.
- Removi o manipulador de eventos [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) do HTML.
- No Javascript adotei o registrador de eventos [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) assim instalando o evento [`HTMLElement:change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) no `checkbox01`.
- Adicionei em CSS um realce para quando o `checkbox02` for desabilitado o seu `label` correspondente fique com a coloração cinza.

```js
const checkbox01 = document.getElementById('checkbox01');
const checkbox02 = document.getElementById('checkbox02');

checkbox01.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  checkbox02.checked = false;           //Ao clicar checkbox01 o checkbox02 deverá ser "deschecado".
  checkbox02.disabled = !this.checked;  //O checkbox02 estará habilitado contrariamente a checagem de checkbox01.
});
```

```css
/*Para o qualquer <label> imediatamente consecutivo a um <input type="checkbox"> desabilitado*/
input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label {
  color: #CBCBC4;     /*Fique cinza*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="checkbox01" id="checkbox01" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="checkbox01">Checkbox01</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="checkbox02" id="checkbox02" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox02">Checkbox02</label>
</div>
```